# How to build html5 apps for ipad in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, html

I am trying to run an html5 app for ipad in ios ,i used web view also.when i run the file in web browser it works fine  but i cannot build the same file in ios.Can Any Help???

Comment: You need to be much more specific with what you are trying to do and what the issue/error is.

Comment: I am trying to run an html5 drawing app with re sizable images( for iPad).but when i build the file using Ios it runs fine but there is no display of anything.can any one help in this issue???

Answer (score 2):

The use of framework depends on your requirements , if you are wishing to have native apps which can use more the native features of iPhone OR if for better performance, deploying on multiple platform.

1. **[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)** isn't made for developing native applications. PhoneGap
   gives you a better choice for sharing applications with your user.
   It is the way to transform your application for mobile phones (with
   a Web Container) and serve it to the Apple App Store and Android
   Market instead forcing the user to make a bookmark or a shortcut on
   his homescreen. PhoneGap allows you to use some of the phones
   features throught APIs to enhance your application.
2. **[Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)** is the choice to build native applications without skills
   in programming language of the mobile phone. For example Titanium
   takes your Javascript code, analyzes and preprocesses it and then
   pre-compiles it into a set of symbols that are resolved based on
   your applications uses of Titanium APIs. So your Javascript is
   compiled one-to-one into the representative symbols of the native
   code. UI is built by using the phones native resources.

**If you are really looking to create the native App using HTML 5, than I would prefer to move with PhoneGap.**